# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I am upgrading Springboot version from 2.x to 3.x and facing below error while running the application. Could you please suggest.

Full Log Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

Comment: You're missing a dependency for JAXB, which could indicate that you might be missing a starter in your dependency list.

Answer (score 1):

You have moved from Spring 2 to Spring 3, and Spring 3 needs at least JDK 17, so I assume you already have JDK 17 or more since you can run the project.
This leads us to the main issue:
The logs show an error in this "JAXBException",
For Java 11 or more, javax.xml.bind package its removed from default classpath.

To solve the issue, add this to pom.xml if you use Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Or add this to build.gradle if you use Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2'
implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2'
```

Comment: Better you go to jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.1, the 2.3.2 hasn't the correct class (javax/xml/bind/JAXBException.class)